# Why can't I use the Context of a Service to display an AlertDialog

Tags: android

Why can't I use the Context of a Service to display an AlertDialog ?

I can do it with Toast!

Comment: If the service in question has an active activity, you are better served consolidating your UI in that activity. If the service in question does not have an active activity -- in other words, the user could be doing anything -- popping a dialog from the service would be very impolite. Most apps would be better served using a `Notification` for that case.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be as implicit as [**`Toast.makeText()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) but in the constructor for [**`AlertDialog.Builder`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) it takes in a `Context` as a parameter.

```
// creates an AlertDialog to the instance of the Context
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert 1");
alertDialog.setMessage("This is an alert");
// display your dialog with an OK button.
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    return;
  } });
```